# Cannot embed sqlite db to winforms application setup deployment

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlite

I have a Winforms application in C# with a SQLite database. Everything works well when I run the application with Visual Studio (I'm using 2013). But when I use the Visual Studio installer and create a setup file and thereafter I install the application on my computer, the db is losing some tables or columns and hence the whole app doesn't work.

Any workarounds for this? Do I need to follow any rules or procedure when creating the setup or while embedding the `.db` file?

Comment: why don't you create DB file and tables pragmatically, instead of embedding DB file in setup?

Comment: Sounds like the installer could be taking the wrong version of the db file.  An older version with these tables and columns missing.  As it should not be able to change anything in the file.  So I suggest to check the references, and remove any old versions you have lying around.

Comment: Another alternative which I have used in the past is that I have embedded the sqlite file into my program, then upon starting the app it checks if the file exists, if not then it retrieves in from the resources in the app and places it on the disk.  Of course in my case I had static data, that could not be updated by the user so nothing was being lost if I done this.